# rails link_to image_tag put

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to change the following link to use a put method, but I cannot figure out where to add it!

```
= link_to image_tag('/images/icons/button-reject.png', :title => 'reject request'), user_request_deny_path(:user_id => req.user_id, :id => req.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
= link_to image_tag('/images/icons/button-reject.png', :title => 'reject request'), user_request_deny_path(:user_id => req.user_id, :id => req.id), :method => :put
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to

> Options
>
> method: symbol of HTTP verb - This modifier will dynamically create an HTML form and immediately submit the form for processing using the HTTP verb specified. Useful for having links perform a POST operation in dangerous actions like deleting a record (which search bots can follow while spidering your site). Supported verbs are :post, :delete, :patch, and :put. Note that if the user has JavaScript disabled, the request will fall back to using GET. If href: '#' is used and the user has JavaScript disabled clicking the link will have no effect. If you are relying on the POST behavior, you should check for it in your controller's action by using the request object's methods for post?, delete?, patch?, or put?.

Answer (score 0):

```
link_to(
  image_tag('/images/icons/button-reject.png', :title => 'reject request'),   
  user_request_deny_path(:user_id => req.user_id, :id => req.id),
  :method => :put
)
```